# How can I make "planetary gravity" or such in the game engine?

Tags: python, game-engine

I want to make a space game where you launch a satellite and see how far you can get it using "gravitational slingshots" (using planets to have your satellite orbit the planet for a short period of time, and then break out and slingshot around another planet or star). I have tried to use a few python scripts to make objects have gravity, but none of them are working. If any of you knows of a code that works well, please tell me. Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/73591